# Token for paging in ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, paging, objectdatasource

I have an ObjectDataSource, which runs queries against a system that uses a token for paging.

On the first call, say to get the first 10 results, I get this token back from the server, and I should use it again in subsequent calls, e.g. to get results from 11 to 20.

Is there a way I can configure the ObjectDataSource to use such a token?

Answer (score 0):

If, say, you have your ObjectDataSource defined like this:

```
<asp:objectdatasource
      id="ObjectDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      SelectMethod="GetData"
      TypeName="Company.DataManager" />
```

You can then define the Company.DataManager type and its GetData method so that is receives the token on the 1st time, stores it and then passes it on (in the form of a parameter of some kind) to the system you query data from.

Comment: and I can also get the token back? I can have a parameter that is a ref or out parameter?

Comment: I think you can manage this token from within the that DataManager class. But if you need it elsewhere, of course you can return it, why not. Or maybe you can store it in session, if it's user-specific.